# CMake unit test issue with custom command and dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I'm facing a problem where I build a shared library and a unit-test executable (which is in a sub directory). I want to execute this test as a POST_BUILD operation for the shared library. So I gave

```
Add_Custom_Command (TARGET ShLibName POST_BUILD COMMAND unit_test_exe)
```

CMake throws an error message during generation process:

```
CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle):
"libCUEUtilities" of type SHARED_LIBRARY depends on "UtilitiesUnitTest" 
"UtilitiesUnitTest" of type EXECUTABLE depends on "libCUEUtilities"
```

At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY. Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.

So, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'm using CMake 2.8.1 (RC3) with VS2005 generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run a unit test every time the shared library is compiled. Since the test executable already depends on the shared library, you can change the `add_custom_command` to run once the unit test executable has been built. For example:

```
add_library(CUEUtilities SHARED ${CUEUTILS_LIBRARY_SOURCES})
add_executable(unit_test_exe ${UNIT_TEST_EXE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(unit_test_exe CUEUtilities)
add_custom_command(TARGET unit_test_exe POST_BUILD 
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/unit_test_exe)
```

Changing any of the library sources will cause the library to be recompiled. Since the executable has a dependency on the library, the exe will get relinked, and finally the post-build step will be run again.